# Unable to set text in EditText Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin and i was trying to make a simple plus minus controller, so the layout has two `buttons`, Plus and Minus and an EditText both are inside a fragment, the issue is that when i'm trying to press one of the buttons the app crash on `.setText` with error Resuource not found.

So the question is what is the right way to set text in an EditText inside a fragment?

Here is my code:

FirstFragment.tk

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btnPlus).setOnClickListener {
        changeQta(it)
    }

    view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btnMinus).setOnClickListener {
        changeQta(it)
    }
}

private fun changeQta(v: View) {
    val txtQta = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txtQta)
    val curVal = txtQta?.text.toString().toInt()
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.btnMinus -> {
            if (curVal > 1) {
                txtQta?.setText(curVal - 1)
            }
            if (txtQta?.text.toString().toInt() == 1) {
                v.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
        R.id.btnPlus -> {
            txtQta?.setText(curVal + 1)
        }
        else -> return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an `int` to `setText` method.
`setText` method is overloaded and it calls the  `public final void setText(@StringRes int resid)` since this method expects an int and that too a string resource but the `int` you are passing to it is not a valid `StringRes` so it causes `ResourceNotFoundException`.

The solution is to convert the int to `String` and then pass it to the `setText` method.

```
yourTextView.setText((curVal - 1).toString())
```

or

```
yourTextView.setText("${curVal - 1}")
```

Whichever way you prefer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are a bunch of `setText` methods (which come from `TextView`, which is `EditText`'s superclass) - [one of them takes a single `Int` parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)):

> `setText(int resid)`
> Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier.

So because you're passing in an `Int`, it assumes that's a resource ID (things like `R.id.btnPlus` and `R.string.coolText` are just `Int`s), but you don't have an ID with that number, which is why it's saying `Resource not found`.

You want this version:

> `setText(CharSequence text)`

So you need to explicitly cast your integer to a `String` (which is a type of `CharSequence` btw)

```
txtQta?.setText((curVal - 1).toString())
```

or you could do it in a string if you like

```
txtQta?.setText("${curVal - 1}")
```

---

by the way, when you do things like this:

```
val curVal = txtQta?.text.toString().toInt()
```

you need to add the `?` at each step, so it skips each time if the value passed along is null, otherwise you might call `toString()` on `null` (which is fine) and then `toInt()` on that (which will crash)

```
val curVal = txtQta?.text?.toString()?.toInt()
```

or if you like

```
val curVal = txtQta?.let { it.text.toString().toInt() }
```

in both cases `curVal` will be the nullable type `Int?` because that expression can return null (that's why you're null checking each step with `?`)