# Kotlin set text

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I want to change static strings in my TextView with returned data from API but it does not change the values.

## Code

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(
  Request.Method.POST, url,
  Response.Listener<String> { response ->
   val responseObject = Gson().fromJson(response, DriverIncome::class.java)

     val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_home, null)
     val mMonth: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.this_month_value) as TextView
     val mTotal: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.total_price_value) as TextView

     mMonth.setText(responseObject.month)
     mTotal?.setText(responseObject.total)
   },
   Response.ErrorListener { error ->
     Toast.makeText(context,"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
     .show()
   }
)
```

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739387/unable-to-set-text-in-edittext-kotlin) and this way `mMonth.text = responseObject.month` none of them worked.

## Update

As it was asked here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_header"
        android:layout_width="483dp"
        android:layout_height="233dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/headerImage"
        android:src="@drawable/main_header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/avatar"
        android:maxWidth="25dp"
        android:maxHeight="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.879"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="224dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mainname"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.042"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="@string/launryku"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textFontWeight="@integer/fifty"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maindescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/fasteasyclean"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textFontWeight="@integer/thirthy"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_header"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainname"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bell"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/notifications"
        android:src="@drawable/notification"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.957"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/this_month_income"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_header"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/month_image"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/month_image"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/month_income" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/thismonth"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/thismonth"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/this_month_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/this_month_value"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/total_income"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_header"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/totla_image"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/total_image"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/total_income" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_price"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/totalincome"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_price_value"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/total_price_value"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## Update 2

fragment code

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    callIncomeAPI()
    return root
}

private fun callIncomeAPI() {
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

    var session = SessionManager(context)
    session.checkLogin()
    var user = session.getUserDetails()
    var token: String? = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    val tokenFull = "Bearer $token"

    val url = "https://example.com/api/incomes/$tokenFull"
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            val responseObject = Gson().fromJson(response, DriverIncome::class.java)

            val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_home, null)
            val mMonth: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.this_month_value) as TextView
            val mTotal: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.total_price_value) as TextView

            mMonth.setText(responseObject.month)
            mTotal.setText(responseObject.total)
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Toast.makeText(context,"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        })
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

Comment: seems like you are referring to the wrong view.

Comment: @rahat you mean in here `view.findViewById(R.id.this_month_value)`?

Comment: You need to clear two things: 
1. If the response is coming properly from the server.
2. Are you referring to the right view? 

And also provide your XML code, it will be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee 1. data are coming properly yes. 2. I'm not sure 3. OK

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee updated

Comment: @mafortis post your code of fragment

Comment: @rahat updated.

Comment: @mafortis You are inflating your fragment layout inside StringRequest block.. 
This line: `val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_home, null)`

Are you sure this is what you want? Generally you should inflate your layout on onCreateView() method....

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee You tell me what is the best to do I'm here to find out that :) I'm not sure of anything :-p

Comment: @mafortis see my answer it will help you.

Comment: @mafortis Ashish answer should solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because you have inflated the view twice. Just assign the textview in `onCreateView` So it will work properly.

```
private var mMonth: TextView
private var mTotal: TextView

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    mMonth: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.this_month_value) as TextView
    mTotal: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.total_price_value) as TextView
    callIncomeAPI()
    return root
}
```

Then just set text :

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(
Request.Method.POST, url,
Response.Listener<String> { response ->
    val responseObject = Gson().fromJson(response, DriverIncome::class.java)
    mMonth.setText(responseObject.month)
    mTotal.setText(responseObject.total)
},
Response.ErrorListener { error ->
    Toast.makeText(context,"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show()
})
```

Comment: `mMonth.setText(responseObject.month)` is undefined inside `callIncomeAPI`

Comment: @mafortis did you set variable on global level ?? see my code i have declared variable outside the `onCreateView`

Comment: oops :) trying again

Answer (score 0):

you are inflating the fragment view twice, use the same view you inflated first:

```
val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
```

use this 'root' to find the text views instead of doing this

```
val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_home, null)
view.findViewById(.....
```